# May I connect 3.6v Li-pol accumulator to 3.3v dc supply?

Tags: dc, 3.3v, lithium-polymer

I have an old Bosch electric owen which has clock and timer on-board. The problem is: on each electricity fail (even milliseconds) this clock resets to the time edit mode and zummer starts to make sound. To stop this I have to press Edit Mode button twice. It's boring.
I have disassembled the clock module and found no battery there. Only the 470 uF capacitor in the 3.3v DC which powers the IC. But as I guess, this capacitor does not help on AC failures.
I have tried to replace the cap, no success.
My idea is to add the small Li-pol accumulator in parallel to this capacitor. Those accums usually installed in car electronics and have some schematics on-board (I guess stabilizer). Is it a normal mode for these accumulators? Will it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to join two supplies: joining diodes.

[image]

Let me explain what's going on here:
A and B are your voltage sources. Imagine there is no R. So the Out will be powered from the higher of the two voltages (A-ddrop or B-ddrop), and the lower voltage source will give no current, it won't be able to send current to the other side of the diode, the voltage there is too high for our lower voltage source. Put a large cap instead of R, and if one of the supplies fails, the other one will keep powering the thing, and the diodes will block current in the reverse direction (if A shuts down, you don't want current from B to flow into A).

As for voltage levels - you'll have to consult the datasheet. Considering the clock thing uses very tiny current, you may just stupidly want to discharge Li-Po to 3.3V, it will still be enough for eternity, especially considering you will actually use its power very little, only during your blackouts. Most likely, you can't go over 3.3V with that thing (well, nobody will die from 3.4, but don't risk going higher). You have to look up the chip specs, but those things usually run only at 3.3. If you have no idea, assume 3.4V is maximum. So use two schottky diodes (available in ebay diode sets too), they have 0.15V voltage drop, so discharge Li-Po to 3.4 and hook it up. And yes, you may need to cut a trace or something to put a Schottky between 3.3VDC source and the clock (it will work fine from slightly dropped 3.15V voltage too).

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. Unfortunately, yes, the accum change will not allow me to power the circuit for infinite time. So the idea was to keep the accum charged from the main circuit. And when the main power off during blackout, the accum will start discharging to the clock.

Comment: So as I got, it's not possible to simple connect in parallel.

Comment: Do you know how that circuit works (the one linked with Li-pol accum)?

Comment: you could put a diode between 3.3V and Li-Po before the meeting diodes. That way your battery will never fall below 3.2-3.15 (3.3-schottky voltage drop, at low currents it is smaller) and will always give effective 3.0+ volts (lost another 0.1-0.15 on the meeting diodes). Anything running on 3.3V runs down to 2.7 or so, 3.0V will definitely work, capacitor smoothens transition. IMPORTANT: sort schottkies on some mouser by leakage current, some have significant reverse current, but there are plenty good ones, or good enough for this application